# bottle on cherrypy server + ssl

Tags: python, ssl, cherrypy

I am trying to run Bottle on top of Cherrypy's server. I want to get SSL Support.

So far I have tried this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, route
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

app = Bottle()

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return "Hello"


server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
            ('0.0.0.0', 443), app)

server.ssl_adapter.private_key = 'server.key'
server.ssl_adapter.certificate = 'server.crt'
server.start()
```

But the above throws an ArgumentError that I can't set properties on a None object (ssl_adpater).
Apparently I need to set the ssl_adapter property to some object that derives from SSLAdapter, but I couldn't find any examples.

I am using Python 2.7 and Cherrypy 3.2.2

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning to run CherryPy as a standalone server or behind a web server like Apache Httpd or Nginx?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
import web
from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
from web.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter

ssl_cert = "path/to/ssl_certificate"
ssl_key = "path/to/ssl_private_key"

CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter = BuiltinSSLAdapter(ssl_cert, ssl_key, None)
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried the following, but hopefully, it should point you in the right direction.

[WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) is typically for communication between a web server like Apache Httpd and a Python web application, where the requests are handled by the web server and handled by the Python application. Since you want a standalone application, using a WSGI adapter doesn't sound quite right, although this is mentioned in [this document](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ssl) (but for an old version of CherryPy).

Newer versions of CherryPy use `cherrypy.quickstart(...)` for their standalone servers. This sounds more appropriate for your application. I would suggest using a configuration as described [on this page](http://www.zacwitte.com/using-ssl-https-with-cherrypy-3-2-0-example), something along these lines:

```
config={
    'server.socket_port': 443,
    'server.ssl_module':'pyopenssl',
    'server.ssl_certificate':'/.../host.crt',
    'server.ssl_private_key':'/.../host.key',
    'server.ssl_certificate_chain':'/.../ca_certs.crt'
}

cherrypy.config.update(config)
cherrypy.quickstart(...)
```

This would also be more in line with the [`_cserver` documentation](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cpserver.html#module-cherrypy._cpserver).

(By the way, port 443 is the default for HTTPS, not 433.)